# Detect if an object has been disconnected from its clients

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I am having an issue with automating an Excel file. The VBA script within Excel first opens a Word application and Word document:

```
    Dim wordApp As Object
    Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    
    vPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(vPath & "\test.doc")
```

And then I call a subroutine within the Word document passing some data from the Excel file:

```
    Call wordApp.Run("StartWithData", variable1, variable2)
```

If Excel detects that an error occurs in that subroutine, I close the Word document and Word application from Excel in a label I call `Err1`:

```
    On Error Goto Err1
    'all the code from above
    Exit Sub
    
    Err1:
    wordDoc.Close wdCloseWithoutSaving
    wordApp.Quit SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
    Set wordDoc = Nothing
    Set wordApp = Nothing
```

This works perfectly fine under normal circumstances; however, if the Word document or application are closed before the `Err1` label executes (such as the user manually closing the document), I get the following error:

> Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)':
> Automation error The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.

which makes perfect sense because the `wordApp` and/or `wordDoc` variables still reference the Application and Document objects and those objects do not exist anymore (yet are also not considered to be `Nothing`).

So here is my inquiry: Is there a way to check if an object has been disconnected from its client before the run-time error occurs so as to avoid having to rely on `on error resume next`?

```
Such as:
    
    If Not isDisconnected(wordDoc) Then
    wordDoc.Close wdCloseWithoutSaving
    End If
    
    If Not isDisconnected(wordApp) Then
    wordApp.Quit SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
    End If
```

**Update 1:**

After looking at [omegastripes' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33701090/detect-if-an-object-has-been-disconnected-from-its-clients/33702391#33702391), I realized that the error given above only occurs when the document (`wordDoc`) was the object that got disconnected. If the Word application (`wordApp`) is what got disconnected, I get the following error:

> Run-time error '462':
>
> The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable

Comment: Why don't you just check the error object? `Err.Number` or `Err.Description` - If the object has disconnected because it's closed, then there's nothing to check - so you can't check that.

Comment: @MacroMan That's a good thought; however, the error that gets thrown is Error 440: "Automation Error" which will get thrown for several different reasons including the object being disconnected as well as any error occurring in the remote procedure call (Word's subroutine).

Comment: I suppose you could check if the Word application is still running (which is quite simple) but checking if something is disconnected is going to be very tricky, if at all possible, the very fact that's it's not connected means that it's properties and methods can't be accessed. Only other thing you can try is seeing if the `wordApp` object returns `Nothing`

Comment: @MacroMan It's definitely not set to `Nothing`. Would it be possible to check if the Word application is still running without being able to access its properties and methods? That would also be able to solve my problem, but that seems like it's along the same lines as checking if it's disconnected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the below example:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim wordApp As Object
    Dim wordWnd As Object
    Dim wordDoc As Object

    Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set wordWnd = wordApp.Windows ' choose any object property as indicator
    wordApp.Visible = True ' debug
    Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\test.doc")
    MsgBox IsObjectDisconnected(wordWnd) ' False with opened document
    wordDoc.Close
    MsgBox IsObjectDisconnected(wordWnd) ' False with closed document
    wordApp.Quit ' disconnection
    MsgBox IsObjectDisconnected(wordWnd) ' True with quited application
End Sub

Function IsObjectDisconnected(objSample As Object) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    Do
        IsObjectDisconnected = TypeName(objSample) = "Object"
        If Err = 0 Then Exit Function
        DoEvents
        Err.Clear
    Loop
End Function
```

Seems any type detection of the variable, which references to the intrinsic Word objects, like `.Documents`, `.Windows`, `.RecentFiles`, etc., made immediately after document close or application quit commands have been invoked, may throw the error 14: Out of string space, while Word application processing the command. The same detection on the `Application`object , may also hang Excel application.

In the example `TypeName()` call is wrapped into OERN loop, that should skip irrelevant results **to get explicit disconnection feedback, relying on the type name**, but not on the error number. To avoid hanging, `.Windows` property is being checked instead of `Application`.

Comment: That's clever! It's useful to note that documents (e.g. `wordDoc`) normally have type `Document` but that is changed to `Object` when disconnected.

Unfortunately your answer, useful as it is, only answers half the question. This is because applications (e.g. `wordApp`) continue to have type `Application` even after they are disconnected. So even though I can detect when a document is disconnected with your answer, I still cannot detect when the application itself gets disconnected. However, you made me realize that I get a different error when the Application is disconnected (see Update 1).

Comment: @Jonathan - So why not trap the error 14 in `IsObjectDisconnected`?  I'm puzzled why you're so averse to using an error handler to detect an error situation.

Comment: @Jonathan, Document can't be disconnected separetely, since it's just a property of Word object. Only the whole application can become disconnected. Checking the type of the variable, that refered to one of the properties, shows the actual state of the application. So if type of the reference to Document property is "Object", then it's explicitly means that application is disconnected.

Comment: @Comintern, I'm not sure the error 14 is stable for disconnected Word Application on any version of Office and Windows.

Comment: @Comintern I'm not opposed to using error handling to handle an error, but I would rather avoid the error to begin with (and include the error handling anyway as a backup).

Comment: @omegastripes There's a difference between a document being closed and an Application being closed. If the user only closes the Document, I get the disconnection error when trying to reference the Document object (`wordDoc`) but the Application can still be open.

Comment: @Jonathan - Fair enough, but what would you do differently if you found out that a server was disconnected through code or an error handling? Wouldn't you be doing the same error recovery regardless?

Comment: @Jonathan, I must confess you are right, reference to the closed document is the same as to the disconnected object. It does make sense to try another properties of application object.

Comment: @Comintern In this case, I'm simply closing the document and application if they have not already been closed. But you are correct in saying the same thing would be done regardless (i.e. skipping code to close them), but I personally believe it's better practice to avoid errors than rely on them.

Comment: @omegastripes I'm going to mark this as the correct answer; TypeName seems like the way to go. I don't really see how the OERN loop is necessary though. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: @Jonathan, as my test shown, OERN helps to avoid errors when type detection made immediately after document close or application quit commands.